# How to separate Angular components (zonejs) from your application

Tags: angular, webpack, extjs, zonejs

I'm not AG expert, I'm a sencha ExtJs expert. A super nice framework that has it all but is not that widespread and popular (due to various reasons) as AG is. So my company started to move pieces to Angular webcomponents using webpack to slowly make the huge app transition away from the less know, ExtJs framework. A framework that is harder to find knowledgeable developers for.

The problem we face. Angular leans heavily on this lib called ZoneJS. And it's SUPER INTRUSIVE!

hijacks stacktraces, caches all errors, hooks into various things like timers, xhr requests, etc... dev tools don't break anymore in the spot I have the error but always in the webpacked zonejs.

From our angular developers I hear (and that's the same thing I read in some articles) it's something you can turn off / not use zonejs but most likely you should not. It would mean you need to handle a lot of things manually...

I'm pretty sure I'm not the only developer facing this. Using any other lib + angular webcomponents... I'm wondering how other people solve this? They just swallow the pain and stop using chrome devTools efficiently? Or is there a way to 'contain' it.

Comment: Do you have any specific problem the zone stacktrace is stopping you from solving? If so, please add a minimal example.

Comment: The zone "stacktrace" is readable, in fact it's not even that bad. But cripples the debugging. Chrome DevTools used to stop at the error. Now they break somewhere in ZoneJs preventing me from decent debugging.. Or...I have to let it run put check the stracktrace, place a breakpoint BEFORE the issue and debug it that way but that's cumbersome and a waste of time.